# Nikon Capture NX 2 System.InvalidOperationException: Object is currently in use elsewhere

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7, drawing

I have Windows 7 professional up to date. I have been struggling to get my Nikon Capture NX 2 program to work. Something happened and no matter what I do I get the same error `System.InvalidOperationException: Object is currently in use elsewhere.` and the application crashes, this happens on mouse hover as the error pops up as soon as I move the mouse after opening the application. The stack trace reveals some insight into what's causing the issue and maybe someone working in this area can help me pinpoint the root of the problem? I have tried already reinstalling all Nikon software including NEF Codec. I have also tried reinstalled Microsoft.Net 4.5.x but nothing helps, I always get this error.

I include the full stack trace below.

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidOperationException: Object is currently in use elsewhere.
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_RawFormat()
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.IgnoreMetafileErrors(Image image, Int32& errorStatus)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle rect)
   at nik.Windows.Forms.Form.Paint_closeButton(Boolean active)
   at nik.Windows.Forms.Form.OnWM_NcHittest(Message& msg)
   at nik.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Capture NX 2
    Assembly Version: 2.3.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.4.7.3000
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Nikon/Capture%20NX%202/Capture%20NX%202.exe
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34238 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
NxController
    Assembly Version: 2.3.0.11420
    Win32 Version: 2.3.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Nikon/Capture%20NX%202/NxController.DLL
----------------------------------------
nik.GUIBase
    Assembly Version: 2.3.0.11326
    Win32 Version: 2.3.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Nikon/Capture%20NX%202/nik.GUIBase.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
nik.Base
    Assembly Version: 2.3.0.11308
    Win32 Version: 2.3.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Nikon/Capture%20NX%202/nik.Base.DLL
----------------------------------------
GUI_Common_Managed
    Assembly Version: 2.3.0.11419
    Win32 Version: 
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Nikon/Capture%20NX%202/GUI_Common_Managed.DLL
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
nik.GUIBase.Resources
    Assembly Version: 2.3.0.11325
    Win32 Version: 
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Nikon/Capture%20NX%202/nik.GUIBase.Resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34234 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
NxCursors
    Assembly Version: 2.3.0.11308
    Win32 Version: 2.3.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Nikon/Capture%20NX%202/NxCursors.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search with the keyword "system.drawing.image.get_rawformat invalidoperationexception" reveals that it probably is a threading issue in the application itself. Many other image editing softwares crashed due to thread safety issues.

Do you have the source code of the application? If yes, check for access of the image by different threads. If you do not have access, you will have to raise the issue with the Nikon support team. Give them a dump for analysis.

A thing that MAY work is to run the application on a VM with a single core. This may reduce the chance of concurrent access. But that is not a guarantee.